# Using parameter with mysql function in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a parameter named "domain", and i want to use it like that

> mysql_select_db($domain_blacklist)

but as you guess, it use $domain_blacklist as a prameter! How can I use only "domain" part as a parameter? thanks for help...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If `$domain_blacklist` is a string, and contains "domain" that command will select the database "domain". Is that not what you want?

Comment: $domain is a string parameter but _blacklist is a constant string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
mysql_select_db($domain . '_blacklist');
```

If this is the answer you were looking for, you should consider going through a few PHP tutorials to get yourself familiar with the language.

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/diving-into-php/

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/25-resources-to-get-you-started-with-php-from-scratch/

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/learn-php-from-scratch-a-training-regimen/

Comment: thank you, actually i am good at c/c++ but new with php and mysql:)